# Print ArrayList from another Activity using ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I'm trying to print a string from `ArrayList` in my another Activity using ListView. I passed a key and values in my **intent** variable. Using this.

MainActivity

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewCart.class);

mealOneIncrement++;
quantityOne.setText(Integer.toString(mealOneIncrement));
mealOneCost = mealOneIncrement * mealOnePrice;
price.setText(Double.toString(mealOneCost));

String mealOneSummayName = name.toString();
String mealOneSummaryDescription = description.toString();
String mealOneSummaryQuantity = String.valueOf(mealOneIncrement);
String mealOneSummaryCost = String.valueOf(mealOneCost);

arrayList.add(mealOneSummayName);
arrayList.add(mealOneSummaryDescription);
arrayList.add(mealOneSummaryQuantity);
arrayList.add(mealOneSummaryCost);

intent.putExtra("data", arrayList);
```

As you can see here I passed `arrayList` variable as value for able to passed this from another Activity.

SecondActivity

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

String[] mealSummary = {};
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mealSummary);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String data = bundle.getString("data");
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm little bit confuse in this part `String data = bundle.getString("data");` I'm not sure if I'm passing a correct variable to my **`ListView`** so I can able to show the `arrayList` variable in my **`ListView`**. Am I doing it wrong? Any help would appreciated :)

Comment: you has mealSummary in ArrayAdapter constructor. You need a data set to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code:

```
intent.putExtra("data", arrayList);
```

you are putting inside the bundle an arrayList of String, but then

```
String data = bundle.getString("data");
```

you are getting just a String. You need to use `bundle.getStringArrayList("data")`.

```
ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList("data")
```

Also (not related to your problem), I recommend to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewCart.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewCart.class);
```

Comment: What's the difference of `this` and `getApplicationContext()`. Also I tried `ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList("data")` but in my `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`. `data` variable is never use and it prints nothing on my listView.

Comment: @Francisunoxx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context. this refers to Activity Context since Activity extends Context https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. You need a data set for the adapter

Comment: you need to use data in the adapter, otherwise the adapter is empty.

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga I casted the `data` variable. `listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) data);` but the file automatically close.

Comment: if you apply the code in my response, then data is an ArrayList<String>.. you cannot cast it to ListAdapter.. you need to create an adapter USING that data.

`mealSummary = (String[]) data.toArray();`
`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mealSummary);`

Answer (score 0):

Pass Arraylist as putStringArrayListExtra,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewCart.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", arrayList);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Get your ArrayList using getStringArrayListExtra,

```
    arrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify this a bit.

In your secondActivity get the data like

```
ArrayList<String> data = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
```

Now you got your data in an arrayList. If you wish to add this data to mealSummary then use,

```
mealSummary = (String[]) data.toArray();
```

Don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`